# Accessing the original property of an inherited modified object

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Reading for Inheritance in "Javascript The Definitive Guide" I read

> If [an object] previously inherited the property x, that inherited property is now hidden by the newly created own property with the same name.

I created an example to understand it better

```
var o = {x:1};
var p = Object.create(o);
p.x = 5;
console.log(p.x); //5
console.log(p); //Object {x: 5, x: 1}
```

In this case, is it possible for any reason to access the property `x` with value `1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
delete p.x;
```

You might also be able to do:

```
p.constructor.prototype.x;
```

but that is not particularly robust as the constructor property is writable and if the object is constructed using Object.create, it's constructor is the Object function and it's prototype is not `p`'s prototype. Even if it references an object, its prototype property may not be the object you seek.

You can also do:

```
p.__proto__.x;
```

but that is non–standard, not supported in all browsers and the future of `__proto__` seems uncertain.

So perhaps best to do something like:

```
if (p.hasOwnProperty('x')) {
  var x = p.x;
  delete p.x;
  var x2 = p.x;
  p.x = x;
}
```

But note that this may affect the order that properties are returned from a for..in loop if that is important (it shouldn't be since order isn't guaranteed and isn't consistent between browsers anyway, but this makes it more likely to be different).
    p.x